# Testing a Launch Configuration Delegate for an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, automated-tests

I want to test my LaunchConfigurationDelegate, but I'm having trouble mocking the eclipse classes for the launch method. I am using Mockito, and I get a NoClassDefFoundError for the ILaunchConfiguration mock when I run the test. The test looks like this

```
@Test
public void testLaunch() {
    ILaunchConfiguration config = mock(ILaunchConfiguration.class);
    ILaunch launch = mock(ILaunch.class);
    IProgressMonitor monitor = mock(IProgressMonitor.class);
    MyLaunchConfigurationDelegate launchDelegate = new MyLaunchConfigurationDelegate();

    try {
        launchDelegate.launch(config, "run", launch, monitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How do I test a launcher?